# Pulling data feed from AutoTrader

Tags: xml, datafeed

I have been searching Google and not really found any results that help - We list as a dealer on Autotrader and was told by our rep there that we can't pull the data feed of our vehicles from their website unless they create and host a website on their servers. Does anyone know if it would be possible to pull data from there so we can have our stock show on our website instead of doubling the work by adding them to AutoTrader AND our website? Alternatively anyone have any clever ideas as to a way I can just upload to Autotrader and display the mon our site aswell?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but there is a charge for it through Autotrader.

Another option is to create your own feed and upload from there to Autotrader. This is no charge for this method.

Comment: Ask the support desk for the CDF2 document

Answer (score 0):

XML2U.com can do it for you by capturing your Autotrader listings and converting the data to an XML feed.